# Upgrade Bootstrap in Rails 7 app with esbuild

Tags: ruby-on-rails, esbuild, rails-sprockets, jsbundling-rails

Gemfile

```
ruby '3.1.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0'
gem 'pg' , '~> 1.4.3'
gem "jsbundling-rails" 
gem "sprockets-rails" 
gem "turbo-rails"
```

➜ yarn upgrade bootstrap

Results in:

`├─ bootstrap@4.6.2`

package.json is the similar `"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",`

How do I upgrade to Bootstrap 5?

Although app/assets/builds/application.css has `* Bootstrap  v5.2.1`

Trying to sort out asset pipeline in Rails 7 while trying to sort out problems with Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Change `package.json` to `"bootstrap": "^5.2.1",` and then run
`yarn  install`
`yarn upgrade`

`yarn add` and `yarn remove` updates `package.json`.

`yarn outdated` is helpful too, but I haven't followed through on understanding the dependencies and pitfalls.